# What local group should user belong to be able to run windows task as that user

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, tasks

When I assign user to a task, I get warning message "This task requires that the user account specified has Log on as batch job rights", but then I can click ok and it keeps this user assigned for that task.

What local group other than Administrators can I assign that user to be able to avoid that warning message and run tasks as that user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to remember that Task Scheduler assigns the "Batch logon" privilege to users automatically... But you can assign it manually (to both users and groups) via `secpol.msc` → *User Rights Assignment* → *Log on as batch job*.

Comment: Thank you, removed user from admin group and added to that right and it does not give me that warning anymore. It was not in that list, so system did not add it automatically.